# Resize a tableview to the last row in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, resize, height

I want to create something like a autocomplete textview in android, that means tableview in a overlay view to display the result of a searh. To do that, I made a view (required to show a specific background) that contains the tableview. That works fine but when the tableview has only 1 row, the tableview does not resize its height.

I write

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

but it just suppress the excess of separator, not change the height.

Could you help me please?

[image]   [image]

Comment: Show me your Screen

Answer (score 0):

You should update tableView's frame manually. 
If you're using autolayout, add an IBOutlet for tableView's height:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I assume tableView's height is limited with some fixed value. If it depends on the screen height, just replace `maxTableViewHeight` with a computed variable.

```
let maxTableViewHeight = CGFloat(300)
```

Create a method to update height of tableView. It will make sure tableView is resized if it's content height is less then maxHeight:

```
func updateTableViewFrame() {
    autocompleteTableView.layoutIfNeeded() //to make sure you have updated contentSize
    let height = autocompleteTableView.contentSize.height
    heightConstraint.constant = min(height, maxTableViewHeight)
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now all you have to do is to call this method whenever your datasource updates. In your case this should be changed value of user's input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already found a similar one but it doesn't really work, the problem was to determine the real size of a tableview after reloaded.

Comment: Anyway, I changed the way to do and totally suppress the "autocomplete textview"